# Minimal setup for running a gtk+3 app in X under debian wheezy like kiosk mode

Tags: gtk, gtk3, xorg

What is the minimal setup to run an self written 2D gtk+3 gui on top of X (weston is not possible on this arm platform). Without a full blown desktop environment.
I look for a solution in which as an user, a process starts X and then my gui. If my gui quits (this should never be happen, but when) the system should reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a default user, possibly enabling [automatic login](https://superuser.com/questions/211236/automatic-log-in-in-linux) for him. You should then create a `.xinitrc` in this user's home directory that calls whatever you need, e.g.:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Put any valid window manager here
openbox &
myapplication
shutdown -h
```

Comment: This dosn't work. On an fresh installed Debian Wheezy i've installed `apt-get install openbox xfce4-terminal`, edited `/etc/inittab` and replaced `1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1` with `1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f root tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1` and created `~/.xinitrc` with this content `#!/bin/sh
openbox &
xfce4-terminal
shutdown -h`.

After reboot root is auto login on tty1 but no X server is started.

Comment: The linked question provides different ways of logging in automatically in X, none of which is what you did. The [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Xorg) suggests to install `gdm`, so you should follow the first answer.